# Python перехват событий клавиатуры на android

Tags: python, android

Добрые люди возможно ли на Python сделать кейлогера для Android?
Можно подключиться к событиям стандартной клавиатуры и записать в лог, или нужно свою клавиатуру создавать?
есть какие-либо мысли по этому поводу?
Спасибо!

Comment: если делать внутри приложения, то ведь можно дефолтными средствами андроида ловить нажатия, зачем питон вообще? уточните задачу пожалуйста

Comment: https://www.computerforensicsworld.com/how-to-make-a-keylogger-in-python-for-mobile-2/
здесь есть информация

Comment: Andrew скажите пожалуйста как деф средствами телефона это сделать?